# How to get text between <option> tag in servlet </option>

Tags: jsp, select, servlets, request, html-select

I have select in my index page. It looks like below

```
<div id="dropdown" class="input-group" style="width:50%">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2" onchange="javascript:document.form1.submit();" style="width : 250px">
                        <option value="C:/path1" >option 1/option>
                        <option value="C:/path2" >option 2</option>
                        <option value="C:/path3" >option 3</option>
                        <option value="C:/path4" >option  4</option>
                        <option value="C:/path5" >option  5</option>
                        <option value="C:/path6" >option 6</option>
                    </select> 
                </div>
```

I need value of "Value" attribute i.e., "C:/path1" which I'm able to fetch in Servlet using

```
String value= request.getParameter("select2");
```

Now I need to fetch text between    tag i.e., I need "option 1" or anything based on selection. How can I do it. Kindly help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With form you can only `value` of selected option if you want the option label as well then you need to write extra logic to send the data to server.

```
<div id="dropdown" class="input-group" style="width:50%">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedLabel" id="selectedLabel">
    <select class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2" onchange="javascript:getSelectedLabel(this);" style="width : 250px">
       <option value="C:/path1" >option 1/option>
       <option value="C:/path2" >option 2</option>
       <option value="C:/path3" >option 3</option>
       <option value="C:/path4" >option  4</option>
       <option value="C:/path5" >option  5</option>
       <option value="C:/path6" >option 6</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

JS: using this function you set the option label to hidden field and the hidden field will be sent along with your form data.

```
function getSelectedLabel(sel) {
    document.getElementById("selectedLabel").value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

Server side:

```
String value= request.getParameter("select2");
String label = request.getParameter("selectedLabel");
```

Comment: Hi Srinu . I would like to get that value in Servlet not in js. Can you please help me how to fetch in servlet.

Comment: @newbie22, by default html form will not send the `option` text to server. If you want the text then you need send it explicitly. In js I am setting the value to hidden variable so that the value will be available for server. In my code I added a hidden variable and setting value to it before form submission.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Srinu . I tried your code. I think this way is best. But when I print that hidden text value in servlet I'm getting null value

Comment: the hidden field should inside `form` tag then only the value will sent to server. Also verify hidden field has `id` attribute or not, coz in js we are using `document.getElementById` set the value.

Comment: Yes @Srinu it is inside <form> tag and it has ID. But still when I try to fetch in servlet using String services = request.getParameter("selectedLabel"); I'm getting no value or empty string

Comment: did you changed `onchange` event of `selectbox` to `"javascript:getSelectedLabel(this);"` ?

Comment: Thanks - this: function getSelectedLabel(sel) {
    document.getElementById("selectedLabel").value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    document.form1.submit();
} HELPED!

Answer (score 0):

here the simple and quick solution.

Try this

```
<select class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2" onchange="javascript:document.form1.submit();" style="width : 250px">
                    <option value="C:/path1_option 1" >option 1/option>
                    <option value="C:/path2_option 2" >option 2</option>
</select>
```

If your send the data to servlet like this (path + option text) the you can get the data by request.getParameter() method and split the data using java code.

```
String value= request.getParameter("select2");
String vals[]  = value.split("_",0);

for(String v : vals){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

so, you can get these two values....

Comment: Nope...Still getting the value of "value" attribute

Comment: you can get the value of path plus and option value right ? then whats the porblem ?

Comment: Nope. I'm getting just path value. I also tried String vals[]  = value.split("_",1); It didnt work. If I select "Option1" I should get "option 1" not "C:/path1_option 1"

Comment: I dont want to alter path value also...because I'm using it else where

Comment: how you send the data with form ? can you send me the full code and can you able to get the value (path) in your code before ?